# ios : UITableView is showing data when i tap on it

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello i'm creating custom contact view using `UITableView`. I fetched all contacts and using table `relodData` but it not showing in table. On a single tap on table then data is visible. In view will appear i'm calling to fetch all contacts in phone and on completion it will reload `tableView` to make contact visible but it shows if i tap on it or open other view and come back.

```
#import "CMContatcsVC.h"
#import "CMContatcsTableCell.h"

@implementation CMContatcsVC 

//======================================================================================================================================================
#pragma mark - VIEW LIFE CYCLE
//======================================================================================================================================================

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];

    [self fetchAllContactsCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {


        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"COUNT_IN_COMPLETION_HANDLER :: %lu", (unsigned long)self.contactArray.count);
    }];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

//======================================================================================================================================================
#pragma mark - TABLE VIEW DELEGATES METHODS
//======================================================================================================================================================

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"TABLE SECTION");
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"TABLE ROWS :: %lu",(unsigned long)self.contactArray.count);
    return self.contactArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSLog(@"TABLE CELL FPR ROW");
    CMContatcsTableCell *contactCell = (CMContatcsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CMContatcsTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    @try
    {
        CMCustomContacts * contact = [self.contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [contactCell.profileImgView setImage:contact.profileImage];
        [contactCell.nameLabel setText:contact.firstName];
        NSLog(@"TABLE CELL CNT NAME :: %@", contact.firstName);
        [contactCell.contactLabel setText:[contact.phoneArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"TABLE CELL EXCEPTION :: %@", exception.description);
    }
    @finally
    {}

    return contactCell;
}

//======================================================================================================================================================
#pragma mark - FETCH ALL CONTACTS
//======================================================================================================================================================

-(void)fetchAllContactsCompletionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error))completion
{
    self.contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (granted)
        {
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactNamePrefixKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey,
                              CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey];

            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"ERROR IN FETCHING CONTACTS :: %@", error.description);
            }
            else
            {
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts)
                {
                    @try
                    {
                        CMCustomContacts *newContact = [[CMCustomContacts alloc] init];
                        newContact.phoneArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        newContact.emailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                        newContact.firstName = contact.givenName;
                        newContact.lastName = contact.familyName;

                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                        newContact.profileImage = image;

                        for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers)
                        {
                            NSString *phone = [label.value stringValue];
                            if ([phone length] > 0)
                            {
                                [newContact.phoneArray addObject:phone]; NSLog(@"PHONE :: %@",phone);
                            }
                        }

                        for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.emailAddresses)
                        {
                            NSString *email = label.value;
                            if ([email length] > 0)
                            {
                                [newContact.emailArray addObject:email];  NSLog(@"EMAIL :: %@",email);
                            }
                        }

                        [self.contactArray addObject:newContact];
                    }
                    @catch (NSException *exception)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"EXCEPTION IN CONTACTS :: %@", exception.description);
                    }
                    @finally
                    {
                        NSLog(@"FINALLY");
                    }
                }

                NSLog(@"COUNT OF CONTACTS :: %lu", (unsigned long)self.contactArray.count);
            }
        }
        completion(granted, error);
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: try to reload tableview on main thread

Comment: it is already done in completion block in viewWill appear

Comment: i said ON MAIN THREAD, look at NDoc's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always update your `UI` on main `thread`, so call `reloadData` of `TableView` on main `thread` like this.

```
[self fetchAllContactsCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }        
    NSLog(@"COUNT_IN_COMPLETION_HANDLER :: %lu", (unsigned long)self.contactArray.count);
}];
```

Comment: you are making block and it will work in `async` manner, on background thread. Now if you want to make changes on UI, You need to use main thread for that like i have done, otherwise it will also work in background and slow. You will get more idea if you will search on google about `change UI on main thread iOS`.